# Umbraco 7.2.1 MVC project in Visual Studio 2013 hangs on install page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, umbraco

I am having trouble running a new `Umbraco 7.2.1` MVC project in Visual Studio 2013.

When I run the solution the Umbraco install image renders but not the install page.

I have attached an image of what I am getting as well as an image of what I expect - could anybody help me here please?

## Actual

[image: Actual]

## Expected

[image: Expected]

## Edit:

I got this to work by:

- Creating a new ASP.NET MVC 4 Web App
- Install Umbraco via NuGet console > Install-Package UmbracoCms

Comment: Try to open your console while installing. Maybe some errors will show up. Also try to see the log in /app_data/logs

Comment: Check the logs as suggested, I'm sure it will provide some insight. Also try running VS as an admin to ensure there are no permissions issues.

Comment: I see that it is quite old question, it would be helpful to all if you write how did you manged to solve it

Comment: If you read the end of the question there's an edit which explains how I did it.

Comment: @NRKirby could you add your own solution as an answer instead so the question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems in the past where my umbraco installation has hung on the install screen like you describe. In my experience this seems to occur when there is a full connectionString specified e.g.  if you have the following already specified in your web.config then it tends to fall over

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <remove name="umbracoDbDSN" />
    <add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="server=LOCALHOST;database=my_db;user id=my_user;password=my_password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

but if the connectionstring has not been configured e.g.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="umbracoDbDSN" />
    <add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="" providerName="" />
    <!-- Important: If you're upgrading Umbraco, do not clear the connection string / provider name during your web.config merge. -->
</connectionStrings>
```

It should work ok for you. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The way around this (or any issue installing old versions of umbraco using Nuget and visual studio) is to download the corresponding version from here

http://code.leekelleher.com/umbraco/archive/

When you have downloaded the version that matches the nuget package you installed copy all of the files from the download into the solution folder of your project (select yes to overwrite files)

This will solve almost all issues (screen hang, exceptions thrown) when installing v7 versions of umbraco using nuget

I used this technique to fix issues with 7.2.1 (hanging install screen) ad 7.15.6 (exceptions on start up)